# How can I properly save/convert or read Color to JSON?

Tags: android, json, flutter, colors, null

I want to change the color of the background of my text field using a color picker. (I used flutter_colorpicker)

create_journal.dart

```
late Color _selectedBackgroundColor;

void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _titleController = TextEditingController();
    _controller = FleatherController();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    journalEntry = JournalEntry();
    _selectedBackgroundColor = Color(journalEntry.backgroundColor);
  }

Future<void> saveEntryField(ParchmentDocument document) async {
    final content = json.encode(document.toDelta().toList());
    await JournalDataManager.saveEntry(JournalEntry(
        dateTime: journalEntry.dateTime,
        title: _titleController.text,
        content: content,
        filePath: journalEntry.filePath,
        backgroundColor: _selectedBackgroundColor.value, //// Trying to save backgroundcolor with other elements
    ));
  }

Future<void> _showColorPickerDialog() async {
    Color selectedColor = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Select Background Color'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: MaterialPicker(
              pickerColor: _selectedBackgroundColor,
              onColorChanged: (Color color) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedBackgroundColor = color;
                });
              },
              enableLabel: true,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(_selectedBackgroundColor);
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    if (selectedColor != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedBackgroundColor = selectedColor;
      });
    }
  }
```

journal_*data_*manager.dart

```
static Future<void> saveEntry(JournalEntry entry) async {
    // prepare data
    String jsonString = jsonEncode({
      'dateTime': timeISOString,
      'title': entry.title,
      'content': entry.content,
      'backgroundColor': entry.backgroundColor, // Trying to save
    });

List<JournalEntry> loadJournalEntries = [];
    for (String filePath in filePaths) {
      try {
        String jsonString = await loadEntry(filePath);

        Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonString);

        loadJournalEntries.add(JournalEntry(
            title: jsonData['title'],
            content: jsonData['content'],
            dateTime: DateTime.parse(jsonData['dateTime']),
            filePath: filePath,
            backgroundColor: jsonData['backgroundColor'], // Tries to load
        ));
      } catch (e) {
        dev.log('Error reading JSON file: $e'); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
      }
    }
```

journal_entry.dart model

```
class JournalEntry {

  late DateTime? dateTime;
  String title;
  String content;
  final String? filePath;
  int backgroundColor;

  JournalEntry({
    this.dateTime,
    this.title = 'Title',
    this.content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at rutrum metus, eget semper felis. Morbi blandit metus consectetur eros sollicitudin, a tempus ipsum blandit. Aenean feugiat aliquam egestas. Suspendisse dolor ipsum, imperdiet eget nibh sit amet, pretium malesuada tellus. Mauris ultricies, erat eu maximus viverra, elit sem commodo mauris, eget vestibulum velit nisl nec lorem. Ut convallis vulputate maximus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lorem, non maximus turpis. Mauris at velit blandit, volutpat risus id, finibus diam. Quisque a fringilla ipsum.',
    this.filePath,
    this.backgroundColor = 0xFF879d55,
  }) {
    dateTime = dateTime ?? DateTime.now();
  }

  String get strDateTime => dateTime!.toIso8601String();

}
```

I am trying to save the Color data to the device and accessing it later-on via encoding it to JSON since my other elements are needed to be encoded to JSON in order to be saved in my text fields using a save button. (title, content, etc.)

This is the dev.log error
[log] Error reading JSON file: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Where did I went wrong? Is it possible? If no, is there any turn-arounds? Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look wrong to me but maybe you somehow saved to storage a `JournalEntry` without a `backgroundColor` at some point. In any case you could rework your `JournalEntry` class to be able to deal with null values like this.

```
class JournalEntry {
  DateTime dateTime;
  String title;
  String content;
  final String? filePath;
  int backgroundColor;

  JournalEntry({
    DateTime? dateTime,
    this.title = 'Title',
    this.content =
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at rutrum metus, eget semper felis. Morbi blandit metus consectetur eros sollicitudin, a tempus ipsum blandit. Aenean feugiat aliquam egestas. Suspendisse dolor ipsum, imperdiet eget nibh sit amet, pretium malesuada tellus. Mauris ultricies, erat eu maximus viverra, elit sem commodo mauris, eget vestibulum velit nisl nec lorem. Ut convallis vulputate maximus. Vestibulum sit amet elementum lorem, non maximus turpis. Mauris at velit blandit, volutpat risus id, finibus diam. Quisque a fringilla ipsum.',
    this.filePath,
    int? backgroundColor,
  })  : backgroundColor = backgroundColor ?? 0xFF879d55,
        dateTime = dateTime ?? DateTime.now();

  String get strDateTime => dateTime.toIso8601String();
}
```

This also has an improvement (in my opinion) with how it deals with null values of the `dateTime`

Comment: I managed to make it work without the null issues. However, after I save the backgroundcolor and reopened the app with the saved background color, I cannot change the background color moreover save to different color.